# WillPopScope: make the Android back button pop the actual view

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I followed this [clean navigation in flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/clean-navigation-in-flutter-using-generated-routes-891bd6e000df) to achieve my actual navigation because I had to do some more stuff that with

```
MaterialApp(
   home: Home(), 
   routes:{...}
)
```

wouldn't have worked out fine.
So, in my material app I just define the home like:

```
MaterialApp(home: Home())
```

Now here's the builder of my `Home`:

```
return WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: () async {
                    return false;
                  },
                  child: Navigator(onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute));
            }
```

where Router.generateRoute comes from:

```
class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Splash());
      case ...
  }
}
```

In this way the Android back button is deactivated since it was just closing the app. My question is: instead of deactivating it, is there a way to make it act like a normal back button, through this `WillPopScope` method?

Comment: have you tried `Navigator.pop()` inside the `onWillPop()` ?

Comment: yes, it seems that pop everything, giving back an empty screen

Comment: Sorry your questions isn't clear, what you are actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but, this is what I use in one of my apps in order to send the app to the background instead of closing the app. If no routes can be popped, the app will be sent to background, otherwise, it pops the route.

```dart
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (!Keys.navigatorKey.currentState.canPop()) {
          // Only move to background when there are
          // no routes to pop
          MoveToBackground.moveTaskToBack();
          return false;
        }
        // There is a route, so we pop it
        return true;
      },
```